# What are the different Qualities/Attributes of heroes in league of legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

What are the different types/attributes of heroes?I know a few but what are all of them?

For an example Akali is a assassin, melee, stealth hero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different attributes of heroes are:

- Pusher
- Jungler
- Support
- Assassin
- Ranged
- Stealth
- Mage
- Carry
- Tank
- Fighter
- Melee
- Recommended

These are easily found on the left side of the champions page on your profile page on the client.

Answer (score 2):

- **Assassin**, which can deal a lot of damage very fast but doesn't live long afterwards if the target lives.
- **Carry**, which starts off a little weak but can build really well as the game progresses; often requires the most attention from teammates.
- **Fighter**, or Off-Tank, can take quite a bit of punishment but still does enough damage to be a threat.
- **Mages** do magic damage to enemies and can often disrupt the enemy team in some way to prevent the enemy from focusing too hard on one objective.
- **Tanks** start fights and try to soak up as much attention and damage as possible while the harder-hitting classes tear into the targets.
- **Junglers** are champions who go through the neutral enemy camps instead of laning to gain gold and experience. They usually strike out at other lanes when they can in order to disrupt the enemy and attempt to get kills for themselves or the carries.
- **Melee** have to hit the enemy physically.
- **Pushers** destroy minions quickly to get to the enemy turret faster.
- **Ranged** heroes can attack from a distance.
- **Stealth** heroes can sometimes/conditionally turn invisible.
- **Support** heroes help other champions reach their full potential and keep their partners strong.
- **Recommended** heroes are pretty easy to play general champions, designed for beginners but still strong presence in the game.

All of these attributes are important and fill a vital role for a team, and most champions fill many of these attributes. The trick is finding which kit is best for you and your play style.

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Attributes

Answer (score 0):

assassin, melee, stealth, support, ranged, mage, tank, pusher, fighter, carry, support, jungler, recommended

I think that's all of them.